# Why can we apply the surface area of revolution theorem to a spiral?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, applications

> To find the surface area generated by revolving function f which is smooth on the interval [a,b] and $f(y) \ge0$  around the y-axis we can use the formula $$S=\int_a^b 2\pi rdl =\int_a^b 2\pi f(y)\sqrt{1+[f^{\prime}(y)]^2}dy$$

We have a spiral $x=e^tcost$ , $y=e^tcost$ , $0\le$t $\le \frac{\pi}{2}$

[image]

Since the spiral is given in a parametric form (with t as a parameter) we can re-write the formula as $$S=\int_a^b 2\pi f(t) \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}dt$$

My question is why can we apply this formula and the spiral is not smooth as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is undefined at $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: The form $\sqrt{1+[f'(y)]^2}dy$ is a special case of the more general form $\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$. The more general form can be used in cases where the special case does not work. But also note that $f'(y)$ is $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$, not $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want your parametric equation for $y$ to have $\sin t$ not $\cos t.$   Notice that if you swap the roles of $x$ and $y$ and rotate about the $x$-axis, then everything is fine.  It doesn't matter that $dy/dx$ doesn't exist, since $dx/dy$ does.  If there was a cusp on the curve, that might be another matter.